# How do I check if event.waitUntil actually waits?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, web-worker

I'm kind of new to Service Workers and Promises and I'm wondering how I can check if the SW is actually waiting for the (chain of) actions I want it to perform before releasing the wakelock.

For example:

```
var count = 0;

self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    count = 0;
    event.waitUntil(work());
});

function work() {
    console.log("work()");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        waitSome()
        .then(function(){
            if (count<30) {
                console.log(" -> Waiting: "+ count);
                return work();
            } else {
                console.log(" -> Done: "+ count);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

function waitSome() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        count++;
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(); }, 1000);
    });
}
```

In this case it would be easy to debug but I'd have to keep my dev tools open - in which case the SW is kept alive (or at least less likely to be killed?)

Also, this code is quite simple, what if it was way more complex? How would you make sure that the SW waits for as long as it needs to?

And how do you check if it doesn't keep the wakelock for longer than necessary?

**UPDATE:** Modified code snippet so it actually works :)

Comment: Personally, I don't like this approach. According to your code, there are 29 calls to the `work` function without being resolved or rejected!

Comment: True but it is meant as an example. The work method could be a queue system that handles incoming messages that need to be processed in order (sync)

Comment: Also.. how would you do it, then? :)

Comment: Having a similar issue, as far as I can tell the waitUntil never makes it wait for me